# Ruby carmen 'NameError'

Tags: ruby, carmen

I am using the [carmen](https://github.com/jim/carmen) gem and following the instructions there. When I execute these statements:

```
require 'carmen'
include Carmen

us = Country.named('United States')
```

I get a

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Country
```

even though I have required and included `Carmen`. `require` returns `true` and `include` returns `Object`

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the Github source and documentation you're seeing is for the latest *unreleased* version. Put this in your Gemfile instead:

```
gem "carmen", :git => "git://github.com/jim/carmen.git", :branch => "master"
```

It's probably best to go to [Rubygems](https://rubygems.org/gems/carmen) and subscribe to the library for updates too, as it's not great to have to rely on an untagged branch in a project.

Comment: @sscirrus Since this answer and the question were written, [version 1.0.0 has been released (and a subsequent version)](http://rubygems.org/gems/carmen). Use that.